# Unable to find server tag

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I am working on an old project that has some user controls. On website one of these controls are being called like this:

```
<form id="frmDesignation" runat="server" >
  <table><tr><td>
    <sidenav:menu runat="server" ID="mymenu"></sidenav:menu>
  </td></tr></table>
</form>
```

At the top the user control has been registered:

```
<%@ Register TagName="menu" TagPrefix="sidenav" Src="~/Common_UC/Menu_Sidenav.ascx"%>
```

But I am getting

```
Error   543 Unknown server tag 'sidenav:menu'
```

The user control is in right place, everything else seems fine. Am I missing something?

UPDATE:
As gbs mentioned in his comment, the problem was in my UC itself. It had some build error in itself so MAY BE that's why I was getting the error message (I can't test it now, don't have the code :( )

Comment: Follow @gbs advice.  What you've provided looks correct.  If applicable, clean your solution and rebuild the project.  Ensure that your UC is part of the project.

Comment: How can I ensure that? I mean the UC is inside a folder which is a part of the project, is there anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly two things:

1: There is some issue with your UC itself.

2: You might want to try rebuilding the Project.

Comment: 2. I tried cleaning & rebuilding the project but it didn't help.
1. Is there any common issue which might cause this? Or do you need to see the whole code (the code is pretty big :( )

Comment: No common reason, it's just that if there is some error while building the control, it won't appear on the page. Try-> RightClick the UC in the Solution explorer and select Build Page. See if that succeeds. May be try using the control inside another page.

Comment: You are right, I am getting thousands of errors when I tried to "Build Page" the mentioned UC is using another UC which is using code from another project (and which is not updated). I think fixing that project will solve my problem.